# FB.UI calls crash official Facebook iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

I have a simple facebook web app that uses the facebook javascript SDK. It works fine in desktop browsers and iOS safari but when run within the facebook iOS app all my calls to FB.UI cause the entire facebook app to crash!

Here's an example:

```
  FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'test',
    title: 'test'
    },
    function(response) {
    }
  );
```

but every single one of my calls to FB.UI causes the app to crash

Comment: Please file a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs with an example webpage.

Comment: Ming, I see you work at Facebook, at any idea what I can do as work around. The above example is the simplest I can imagine. Any there are possible prerequisites you can think of that I might be missing?

Comment: I don't work on the JS SDK, and can't offer you a work around. Your best bet is to file a bug. Sorry.

Comment: As Ming stated your best bet is to file a bug. If you can provide a link to your report that would be great to help locate your issue. Thanks